# Mercurial eclipse plugin push different server

Tags: eclipse, mercurial, eclipse-plugin, mercurial-hook, mercurialeclipse

I have installed mercurial and configured in .hgrc file like this:
default (server-1)
default push (server-2)
This works fine in command line as it is using .hgrc file.

I tried using the eclipse plugin for mercurial  which is not reading from .hgrc file ( I have to give repo address and credentials to it), I have given the default server-1 address,  So How can I configure server-2 for push operation ?

Or

how to make my eclipse to read from .hgrc file directly ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the plugin is utilizing the `.hgrc` file (for instance I've never edited it by hand and have a `defult` definition in it).

Try opening the drop-down list of the URL text field in when pushing/pulling, it will contain *server-1* (and probably *server-2* too), and if you select it, the plugin will also fill the user credentials (if you saved them too).

Comment: Hope it helps. If not, try contacting the guys at the [user discussion group](https://groups.google.com/group/MercurialEclipse), they're quite reactive and always ready to help with these sort of problems.

Comment: Hi @rlegendi, I checked my eclipse which one it is using, It is like individual configuration for each repo and it uses repo/.hg/hgrc file instead og ~/.hgrc. Yes Thanks for the google groups link. :)

Comment: If for some reason the repo you want doesn't show in the drop-down list, open the "Mercurial Repositories" view and add the repo there.

Comment: Hi @EvanHaas , you mean to say in repo/.hg/hgrc ?

Comment: Sorry, I meant from within Eclipse.  Window-->Show View-->Other-->Mercurial-->Mercurial Repositories.